# How to crawl a whole website with Headless Chrome Crawler?

Tags: node.js, async-await, web-crawler, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

i've been studying chrome puppeteer to develop a crawler for learning purposes. So i discovered HeadLess Chrome Crawler, a good node package. However, i found some troubles tryng crawl a entire website using this awesome package. I not found in docs where i can do this. I want to get all links from a page and pass them into an array list to crawl them. This is my code now:

```
const HCCrawler = require('headless-chrome-crawler');

(async() => {
  var urlsToVisit = [];
  var visitedURLs =[];
  var title;
  const crawler = await HCCrawler.launch({
  // Function to be evaluated in browsers
  evaluatePage: (() => ({
    title: $('title').text(),
    link: $('a').attr('href'),
    linkslen: $('a').length,
})),
// Function to be called with evaluated results from browsers
onSuccess: (result => {
  console.log(result.links)
  title = result.result.title;
  result.result.link.map((link)=>{
    urlsToVisit.push(result.result.link)
  })
}),
});



await crawler.queue({
  url: 'http://books.toscrape.com',
  maxDepth :0
});
await crawler.queue({
  url: [urlsToVisit],
  maxDepth :0
});

await crawler.onIdle(); // Resolved when no queue is left
await crawler.close(); // Close the crawler
})();
```

So, what i should to do?

My logs:

```
(node:4909) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at Url.parse (url.js:143:11)
    at urlParse (url.js:137:13)
    at Promise.all.map (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/headless-chrome-crawler/lib/hccrawler.js:167:27)
    at arrayMap (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/headless-chrome-crawler/node_modules/lodash/_arrayMap.js:16:21)
    at map (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/headless-chrome-crawler/node_modules/lodash/map.js:50:10)
    at HCCrawler.queue (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/headless-chrome-crawler/lib/hccrawler.js:157:23)
    at HCCrawler.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/headless-chrome-crawler/lib/helper.js:177:23)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/crawlertop.js:30:17
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
(node:4909) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:4909) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[ 'http://books.toscrape.com/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books_1/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/travel_2/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/mystery_3/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/historical-fiction_4/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/sequential-art_5/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/classics_6/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/philosophy_7/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/romance_8/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/womens-fiction_9/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/fiction_10/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/childrens_11/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/religion_12/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/nonfiction_13/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/music_14/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/default_15/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/science-fiction_16/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/sports-and-games_17/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/add-a-comment_18/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/fantasy_19/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/new-adult_20/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/young-adult_21/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/science_22/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/poetry_23/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/paranormal_24/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/art_25/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/psychology_26/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/autobiography_27/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/parenting_28/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/adult-fiction_29/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/humor_30/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/horror_31/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/history_32/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/food-and-drink_33/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/christian-fiction_34/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/business_35/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/biography_36/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/thriller_37/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/contemporary_38/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/spirituality_39/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/academic_40/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/self-help_41/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/historical_42/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/christian_43/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/suspense_44/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/short-stories_45/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/novels_46/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/health_47/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/politics_48/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/cultural_49/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/erotica_50/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/crime_51/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/tipping-the-velvet_999/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/soumission_998/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/sharp-objects_997/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/sapiens-a-brief-history-of-humankind_996/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/the-requiem-red_995/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/the-dirty-little-secrets-of-getting-your-dream-job_994/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/the-coming-woman-a-novel-based-on-the-life-of-the-infamous-feminist-victoria-woodhull_993/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/the-boys-in-the-boat-nine-americans-and-their-epic-quest-for-gold-at-the-1936-berlin-olympics_992/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/the-black-maria_991/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/starving-hearts-triangular-trade-trilogy-1_990/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/shakespeares-sonnets_989/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/set-me-free_988/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/scott-pilgrims-precious-little-life-scott-pilgrim-1_987/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/rip-it-up-and-start-again_986/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/our-band-could-be-your-life-scenes-from-the-american-indie-underground-1981-1991_985/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/olio_984/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/mesaerion-the-best-science-fiction-stories-1800-1849_983/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/libertarianism-for-beginners_982/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/its-only-the-himalayas_981/index.html',
  'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-2.html' ]
(node:4909) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error: Connection closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
    at assert (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/headless-chrome-crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:251:11)
    at Page.close (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/headless-chrome-crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:883:5)
    at Crawler.close (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/headless-chrome-crawler/lib/crawler.js:80:22)
    at Crawler.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/headless-chrome-crawler/lib/helper.js:177:23)
    at HCCrawler._request (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/headless-chrome-crawler/lib/hccrawler.js:349:21)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
(node:4909) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 9)
```

Comment: What "troubles" are you having? Please be more specific about your question. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Varcob yes, i edited with logs

Comment: @Matheus, There, I added a working answer, read thru it and try to understand. If this works, mark as accepted, or ask more questions with new logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code. I will go thru them one my one.

## Problem: Wrong code on `onSuccess`

- You mentioned `result.result.link`, however result has `links`, so the path should be `result.links` instead.
- The map function does not use `link`, you are pushing same data over and over to the `urlsToVisit`

## Problem: Wrong logic on continuous crawling

You have two part of scraping,

- one is to go thru the target page and collect links,
- another is to go thru the collected links.

You need to think them separately.

Moreover, Whenever you `.queue`, it calls immidietely, however your `urlsToVisit` is not complete yet. It probably doesn't have any data at all.

## Solution

- Recursively queue the links. Whenever it finishes crawling, it should queue new links back to the crawler.
- Also let's make sure to catch the errors with `onError`.

Here is a working code,

```
(async () => {
  var visitedURLs = [];
  const crawler = await HCCrawler.launch({
    // Function to be evaluated in browsers
    evaluatePage: () => ({
      title: $("title").text(),
      link: $("a").attr("href"),
      linkslen: $("a").length
    }),
    // Function to be called with evaluated results from browsers
    onSuccess: async result => {
      // save them as wish
      visitedURLs.push(result.options.url);
      // show some progress
      console.log(visitedURLs.length, result.options.url);
      // queue new links one by one asynchronously
      for (const link of result.links) {
        await crawler.queue({ url: link, maxDepth: 0 });
      }
    },
    // catch all errors
    onError: error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });

  await crawler.queue({ url: "http://books.toscrape.com", maxDepth: 0 });
  await crawler.onIdle(); // Resolved when no queue is left
  await crawler.close(); // Close the crawler
})();
```

## Problem: This solution does not solve my problem

You will quickly realize you are not scraping the `links` that you were scraping it was crawling everything using it's own method.

That is why the package has a `maxDepth` option. So that it can go thru the whole website all by itself without the recursive function. Read their doc, try to understand it bit by bit.

Most importantly, **You have to split your code into multiple parts and solve one problem at a time.**

Feel free to explore other options on the document.

Comment: Thanks. Iam studying the api docs to know better how to use maxDepth. You answer gave me a good explanation. I wasn't understand how to use it. But now i can understand it better. I'll still studying it more. Thaks again!

Comment: Is there a way to limit the result URLs to ONLY books.toscrape.com?

Comment: :D `result.options.url.includes(books.toscrape.com)`

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher I don't see url.includes(<string>) in the API @ https://github.com/yujiosaka/headless-chrome-crawler/blob/master/docs/API.md , could it be some other API you are referring to? I had to use "" for includes(), since .includes(books.toscrape.com) did not work, and I got (node:55634) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error:

Comment: plus this is still crawling outside the books.toscrape.com domain, even after using result.options.url.includes(books.toscrape.com)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type object`

The error is stating that `"url"` is of type `object` and not a `string`. The issue lies here

```
await crawler.queue({
  url: [urlsToVisit], // This is an array not a string
  maxDepth :0
});
```

You will need a `for` loop to run over each URL in the array `urlsToVisit` like so

```
urlsToVisit.forEach(function(u) {
  await crawler.queue({
      url: u,
      maxDepth :0
    });
});
```

Also your log states `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)`. Use a `try/catch` block so this error does not pop up

Comment: I tryed do this, but ` This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().` persists